# Error in Ionic project: Uncaught Error: Type Storage does not have 'ɵmod' property"

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I started a new project in Ionic 6.13.1.
So, i added the plugin storage:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

npm install --save @ionic/storage
```

In *app.module.ts* i wrote:

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
```

but *IonicStorageModule* was not recognized, only *Storage* was.

When i declare Storage in Imports section and run

*ionic serve*

there was an error: "Uncaught Error: Type Storage does not have 'ɵmod' property".

I did not wrote any other line in code, only this ones.

How can i solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Angular-based Ionic apps using Ionic storage, you have to use the storage-angular library.

```sh
npm install @ionic/storage-angular
```

Here is a link to the [Ionic Storage](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage) documentation for additional information

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same problem, and the previously accepted answer from Rich Tillis is correct, but for beginners like me maybe not obvious:

According to the [docs](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage), also linked above, you should do the import in app.module.ts as follows:

Note: pay attention to the import: @ionic/storage-angular
So basically everything stays the same, except the import. Well done ionic :)

```js
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```